# Why ELMo's word embedding can represent the word better than glove?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embeddings, representation

I have read the code of [ELMo](https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf).
Based on my understanding, ELMo first init an word embedding matrix `A` for all the word and then add LSTM `B`, at end use the LSTM `B`'s outputs to predict each word's next word.

I am wondering why we can input each word in the vocab and get the final word representation from the word embedding matrix `A` after training.

It seems that we lost the information of LSTM `B`.

Why the embedding can contains the information we want in the language model.

Why the training process can inject the information for a good word representation into the word embedding matrix `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wrong. ELMo also use the output of LSTM for context-dependent representation.

The output only from word embedding is the context-independent representation.

Why the representation is useful?

I think it is because, it is learning the difference between words and the representation is not the real meaning for the word.